# Codeigniter 2.1 - Javascript code inside PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to load JS like this?

```
   <script language="javascript" src="<?php echo JS ?>mali_oglasi/<?php echo $js ?>.php"></script>
```

**JS** is the path to the file and **$js** is the name of the file created in controller (path and name are ok).

```
$data['js'] = ($data['posao'] == 'izmeni' ? 'mali_oglas_izmeni' : 'mali_oglas_pregled');
```

At the begging of the file I want to load I had put this

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript"); ?>
```

and as a part of JS code I have:

```
<?php echo IMG ?>
```

It should echo hole path, but it only show IMG? Is this what I want possible this way or some other way?

Constants:

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', str_replace('system/','', BASEPATH));
define('BASE', $root);
define('CSS', BASE . 'public/css/');
define('JS', BASE . 'public/js/');
define('IMG', BASE . 'public/img/');
define('STORE', BASE . 'public/store/');
```

Comment: 1. what you are trying to achieve? 2. Are `JS`, `IMG` are all constant? As i see it, they are not.

Comment: JS and IMG are constants, and $js is dynamically changed.

Comment: excluding all other codes, concentrating only on thee 1st line, what does source code outputs? does it points to your js file or throws 404 not found error?

Comment: JS file (it has PHP extension) is pointed ok (code is loaded). Problem is in the part where it needs to echo IMG constant, it only echo IMG not path (public/img ....).

Comment: IMG is a constant  or is $IMG use variables not constants you ara sure that you set well IMG constant?

Comment: IMG is a constant defined in **constants.php**  and it is a path to the img folder (apsolut path )

Comment: Please, put the code from constants.php where you declare the `IMG` constant.

Comment: Well, looks like you are trying load de `IMG` outsite of `Controller` context, that is reason that the constants.php is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

Because `JS` is a folder name, you could do:

```
<script language="javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(JS . "mali_oglasi/{$js}.php"); ?>"></script>
```